# Cakephp 4.X - Add via plugin a script block in every page/view

Tags: javascript, cakephp, plugins, block, helper

I have a question about Cakephp 4.X.

Maybe you know a simple and quick way to permanently add a Javascript file to all views in the script block using the plugin system. How can this be achieved?